# How do I perform an airdash with the Winged Boots?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

I recently picked up a nice pair of Winged Boots from a treasure chest. They tell me that they enable me to use the airdash technique! This is great news, only I can't figure out for the life of me how I'm supposed to use it. What button or combination of buttons or button holding maneuver performs the airdash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the way to airdash is to dodge (attack + jump buttons/keys together) in midair!